# Single-supply op-amp (LM324A) output does not change

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, troubleshooting

I am trying to create a non-inverting op-amp circuit using one of the op-amps in the [LM324AN](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/LM324A) IC. Part of the requirements of my project is that I must tie VCC- to ground, so I am operating in single-supply mode. My problem is that my output is not dependent on my input. I have attached my circuit diagram, and I will also explain whats going on:

I am expecting between 0 and 1 V DC input, which I have connected to the non-inverting terminal, for my inverting terminal, I have a 2.2 kΩ resistor and a 4.7 kΩ resistor as my R1 and Rfeedback respectively. I am powering the VCC+ pin with 5 V.

My output is always 3.6 V no matter where the input voltage is between 0 and 1 V. When I change my VCC+, the output changes.

Things I have tried/checked:

- All grounds, including the power supplies for both VCC and VS (input) are common, and connected to all other grounds on the board (including VCC-).
- I have tried using VCC+ = 10 V, and the output scales to 8.7 V which is far higher than my resistor ratio.
- I have experimented with different resistors from the output to ground, including 10 kΩ and 100 kΩ resistors. I have also shorted the output to ground and tried leaving it open-circuited.
  I have also tried adding a 33 Ω resistor in parallel with the input voltage in case that helped, but it didn't.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain it's hooked up correctly? You haven't swapped the + and - inputs, or have power connected to the wrong pin?

Comment: Please show an image of your actual setup.

Comment: What voltage does your amplifier negative pin have? You can start from there if you have checked the connections and it looks ok.

Comment: This acts like the feedback isn't connected, and that the output is just limiting/clamping at Vcc-1.3 V (approximately).

Comment: Hello and Thanks for your responses! I rebuilt my circuit on a breadboard to show you but when I tested that setup it worked! This helped me discover that the IC on my PCB had a short (real not virtual) between the non-inverting and inverting Pins! because my project only needs 2 Op amps I will just use a different op-amp. Thanks again!